# Weird php mysql variable type issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

[image: My db records]

Now I admit I am slightly new to laravel still, but to me this just does not make sense. The model that goes along with this table contains only 2 functions, both containing a relationship statement.

I am using Laravel4, mysql, php 5.5

Any ideas are welcome :D

The database record-definitions are for both DATETIME, allow null and no default value (changed that after the screenshots)

the $challenge variable is part of the data I pass on to the view like so:

```
$challenges = Auth::user()->challenges;
$data['challenges'] = $challenges;

return View::make("challenges/topic", $data);
```

and in the view I use

```
@foreach($challenges as $challenge)
```

read the challenge values (I am aware I cant echo like that without php tags or {{ }}, just easier to explain)

```
echo gettype($challenge->deadline)   // results in string
echo gettype($challenge->created_at) // results in object
```

Comment: Instead of screenshots, which are often hard to read and can't be copy-pasted here, please post plain text.

Comment: `created_at` is Carbon object and `deadline` is simple datetime string. Read about date mutators in Eloquent. And really, `WTF` is like 10yr old boy crying, so next time maybe ask real question.

Comment: @deczo the WTF was intended to be with a wink, not as a cry out, but appreciated the reaction nontheless. I am well aware of the mutators in Eloquent, the problem is, there is no other code related to those fields, all the steps I took I pasted in the image. The data is brand new and not accessed in any other place :)

Comment: I suppose so, that's why I replied anyway. Date mutator are default behaviour for `created_at` and `updated_at` so you would need to disable them to notice unusual effects.

Comment: @deczo Ah, so created_at and updated_at get special treatment even for how eloquent parses them? meaning I need to pull additional strings for other datetime fields? :)

Comment: What you mean by *pull additional strings*?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you access it, if you do:

```
Route::any('test', ['as' => 'test', function()
{
    $a = Article::first();

    var_dump( gettype($a->created_at) );

    $a = DB::table('articles')->first();

    var_dump( gettype($a->created_at) );

}]);
```

You will get:

```
string 'object' (length=6) /// This is Eloquent

string 'string' (length=6) /// This is the QueryBuilder directly accessing your table
```

Comment: This is actually very useful, I wasnt aware the QueryBuilder that effect. However I am parsing both values through eloquent, I will add the code to my OP :)